# Excel: Sum all numbers in a column between two delimiters>

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I had about 50 cells similar to the below. I want to sum only the numbers after the `OT:`  and before the `)`. Some cells will not have `OT:`  or numbers and thus should not be included in the sum. How can I do this?

D: XYZ

D: (OT: 7)

N: (OT: 13)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data lies in column A, with your first item in cell A1, and assuming that you can use column B to keep some temporary data.

Enter the following formula in cell B1:

```
=IFERROR(value(MID(A1,FIND("OT: ",A1)+LEN("OT: "),FIND(")",A1,FIND("OT: ",A1))-FIND("OT: ",A1)-LEN("OT: "))),0)
```

Explained:

`FIND("OT: ",A1)` returns the position of the first occurrence of the string "OT: "

`LEN("OT: ")` returns the length of "OT: ", i.e. 4 including the trailing space

`FIND(")",A1,FIND("OT: ",A1))` returns the position of the first occurrence of ")" after the string "OT: "

`MID(A1,FIND("OT: ",A1)+LEN("OT: "),FIND(")",A1,FIND("OT: ",A1))-FIND("OT: ",A1)-LEN("OT: "))` returns the string between "OT: " and ")", based on the parameters explained in the above.

`VALUE(...)` converts the string into number, so that you can add the numbers.

`IFERROR(..., 0)` convert those unmatched results with `#VALUE!` into 0, so you can add the number without getting an error.

Finally, please fill the formula from cell B1 downwards so that every data in column A has a corresponding formula in column B.  Add up column B:B and that will be the results you needed.

Answer (score 0):

In a new Excel you can use a formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A5,"OT:"),")"),0))
```

where `A1:A5` represents your data range.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish the desired outcome. Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then one could use a combination of `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTSPLIT()` or a combination of `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTBEFORE()` provided in the latter method it assumes that the delimiter `:` after `OT` will be the only last one. Here are my proposals as follows:

---

1. **Using `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(A1:A3,")"),"OT:"),0))
```

---

2. **Using `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTBEFORE()`**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFNA(--TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3,")"),":",-1),0))
```

---

However, if one is not using **Modern Versions** of Excel, then may use the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,")",),1,FIND("OT:",A1:A3)+2,),0))
```

---

- Firstly, using `SUBSTITUTE()` function, removing the closing bracket from the string with nothing.
- Secondly, using `REPLACE()` function, removing the part before including `OT:`
- Adding, `double unary` i.e. `--` to convert text formatted numbers to read as actual numbers as well wrapping within `IFERROR()` to parse the error value with `0`
- Lastly, using `SUM()` to get the sum of the whole array.
- **Note:** If you are not using `MS365` or `Excel 2021` then the above formula needs to be entered with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode.

---